# can't see ether in ethereum wallet

Tags: ether

I sent some ether from kraken to my ethereum wallet in January 2017. Recently, I decided that it is time to receive it.

Etherscan.io shows that it was successfully sent and was in block 3012342. My ethereum wallet is syncing for several weeks now and I still don't see my ether, although, it claims to work on block 4000000+.

This is my wallet address: 0x54f8fbf1915c7a4a6f35faa3d1a3d0ac5907e516

Could you please suggest a way of recovering my ether?

Thank you!

[image: wallet]

[image: sync]

Comment: did you download the blockchain using fast sync?

Comment: i got my ether using myetherwallet and the keystore file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have the private key of your address, you'll always "own" the ether regardless of whether your wallet has been synched or not.

If etherscan is showing your correct balance and you have your private key, the issue is almost certainly wallet synching, which is just a small, fixable issue.

I would try restarting your wallet to re-establish your wallet's connections, sometimes its gotten stuck for me.

The last resort I would try is to export your private key and recover your wallet elsewhere, but only do this as a last resort since this could be insecure.

Comment: thanks mate! I got my ether using myethereumwallet and the keystore file